# selenium-jupiter - Unable to find screenshot file

Tags: selenium-jupiter

When I tried to run the below command with JUnit 5

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests && mvn clean test -pl=test-insight -Dtest="com.myproject.automation.test.settings.**" -Dspring.profiles.active="live" -Dsel.jup.screenshot.at.the.end.of.tests=whenfailure -Dsel.jup.screenshot.format=png -Dsel.jup.output.folder=target/screenshot
```

After that, I couldn't see the screenshot is created. Does anyone help me with my problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to enable surfire-reports.

Comment: Hi @Laura, I enabled surefire-report but it didn't work. Please see the code 
`mvn clean install -DskipTests && mvn clean test -pl=test-insight -Dtest="com.myproject.automation.test.settings.**" -Dspring.profiles.active="live" -Dsel.jup.screenshot.at.the.end.of.tests=whenfailure -Dsel.jup.screenshot.format=png -Dsel.jup.output.folder=target/screenshot surefire-report:report-only`

Comment: I used another report Allure report as a temporary solution at this time. I will look at my script to figure out the root cause. Anyway, thank you so much.